# bridge edge loops making a weird angle between two cylinder

Tags: modeling, vertices, transforms, edges, geometry

Tried bridging two cylinders with bridge edge loops and with addon loop tools: bridge both ways still makes this weird shape?
[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'm not entirely sure why this sometimes happens, but lowering the smoothness value could help.